# implementing Euler method in matlab for second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, eulers-method

I have to use the Euler method for the differential equation : $$\begin{cases}
x^{\prime}=y \\ y^{\prime}=-\frac{k}{m}x-\frac{\beta}{m}x^{3}
\end{cases}$$ with $k=4, \beta =-0.04 , m=1$ in matlab. We already got the code:

```
h=0.1; 
Tmax=50;
n=Tmax/h;
t=[0:h:Tmax];
x(1)=a;
y(1)=b;
for i=1:n
    x(i+1)=x(i)+h*f(t(i),x(i),y(i));
    y(i+1)=y(i)+h*g(t(i),x(i),y(i));
end
plot(t,x)
plot(x,y)
```

I replaced f and g by : `y(i)` and `-4x(i)+0.04x(i)^3` but this did not work.

---

(*error from comment*) we have to choose some starting values and stepsize. When i choose $h=0.1$, $x(1)=5$, $y(1)=0$ i get the errors :

```
Error using plot 
    Vectors must be the same length. Error in Untitled (line 13) plot(t,x).
```

Is there a reason for that? or are there any interesting of not usefull starting points, stepsizes?

---

Could someone help me?

Comment: What exactly did not work? I'd suspect that the array lengths are not exactly equal and that's why the first plot command fails. Change to `t=[0:h:Tmax]; n = len(t)-1;` to get equal lenghts. You might also investigate the plotting functions to make sure that the phase plot is in a different canvas/figure than the component plot. That the multiplication should be written as `-4*x(i)+0.04*x(i)^3` should not have to be mentioned.

Comment: h=0.1;
Tmax=50;
n=Tmax/h;
t=[0:h:Tmax]; 
n = len(t)-1;
x(1)=1;
y(1)=2;
for i=1:n
    x(i+1)=x(i)+h*y(i);
    y(i+1)=y(i)+h*(-4*x(i)+0.04*x(i)^3);
end
plot(t,x)
plot(x,y)
this is what i have now. I get the error : "Undefined function 'len' for input arguments of type 'double'.

Error in Untitled (line 7)
n = len(t)-1;"

Comment: Then use `length` to get the length of the array. And you only need to compute the final value of `n`, the first one is not used. Please add the original error (or its description if no error message) to the question text. As a coding problem, the better place would be the stackoverflow.com forum.

Comment: we have to choose some starting values and stepsize. When i choose h=0.1, x(1)=5 ,y(1)=0 i get the errors : 
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same length.

Error in Untitled (line 13)
plot(t,x). 
Is there a reason for that? or are there any interesting of not usfull starting points,stepsizes? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that floating point arithmetic is not exact. Thus the array `t=[0:h:Tmax]` does not necessarily contain `n+1` elements where `n=Tmax/h`, as you assume for the first plot. Print out the lengths of `t,x` and `t(end)` to see this directly.

Due to the floating point noise it may happen that `n*h>Tmax` so that the last element of `t` is around `Tmax -h`. $h=0.1$ has a binary representation that evaluates to $0.10000000000000000555$, thus $500$ times adding $h$ is computed as $50.00000000000044053649$, which is larger than $T_{max}=50$.

The safest way is to measure the length of `t` directly, `n=length(t)-1`. To ensure that `Tmax` is reached, the time can be constructed as `t=[0:h:Tmax+0.99*h]`.

Or compute `n=Tmax/h`, apply proper rounding to get an integer, and set `t=[0:n]*h`.